# How to tell if JSON object is empty in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "limit": 20,
        "next": null,
        "offset": 0,
        "previous": null,
        "total_count": 0
    },
    "objects": []
}
```

I'm interested in objects: I want to know if objects is empty and show an alert:

something like this:

```
success: function (data) {
    $.each(data.objects, function () {
        if data.objects == None alert(0)
        else :alert(1)
    });
```

Comment: Are you controlling the server-side code that generates the JSON? If so, just set some property equal to zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Array's [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property:

```
// note: you don't even need '== 0'

if (data.objects.length == 0) {
  alert("Empty");
}
else {
  alert("Not empty");
}
```

Comment: There are more robust answers than this. It's actually better to leave off the `== 0` because if `objects` is not array you'll get unexpected results. @GrantU consider checking the others.

Comment: @tybro0103 I don't think so. The check is unnecessary if the server always includes the `objects` key as an array in the JSON output.

Comment: I guess it depends on how much you trust the server

Answer (score 9):

i don't know what is you meaning about empty object, but if you consider

```
{}
```

as a empty object, i suppose you use the code below

```
var obj = {};

if (Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
    alert('empty obj')
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is the best way:

```
if(data.objects && data.objects.length) {
  // not empty
}
```

And it's the best for a reason - it not only checks that objects is not empty, but it also checks:

1. `objects` exists on `data`
2. `objects` is an array
3. `objects` is a non-empty array

All of these checks are important. If you don't check that `objects` exists and is an array, your code will break if the API ever changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `length` property to test if an array has values:

```
if (data.objects.length) {
    $.each(data.objects, function() {
        alert(1)
    });
} 
else {
    alert(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this was what i did, thanks @GilbertSun, on a jsonp callback when I got an undefined with data.objects.length

```
success: function(data, status){
                  if (Object.keys(data).length === 0) {
                      alert('No Monkeys found');
                    }else{     
                      alert('Monkeys everywhere');
                    }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

## Js

```
var myJson = {
   a:[],
   b:[]
}

if(myJson.length == 0){
   //empty
} else {
  //No empty
}
```

### Only jQuery:

```
$(myJson).isEmptyObject(); //Return false
$({}).isEmptyObject() //Return true
```